# Trouble importing CSS from one LWC into another

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, import

I made a LWC to hold common CSS I want to import across different LWCs that I am working on.

Based on these [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lwc_css_share.htm) I created a component called *myComponent* and tried to import it in the CSS portion of one of my other LWCs, let's call it *consumerComponent*.

Here's my code.

**myComponent Metadata**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>49.0</apiVersion>
    <description>My Component</description>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>My Component</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**myComponent CSS**:

`Holds a bunch of css`

**consumerComponent**

```
@import 'c/myComponent';
```

The API version of the *consumerComponent* is also `49`.

However I am getting the following error: `Error during LWC component connect phase: [Class constructor MyComponent cannot be invoked without 'new']`.

Any ideas or leads for this?

Comment: There is a bug in this and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/315665/70823) is the work-around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind just figured it out.

I am using IntelliJ with Illuminated Cloud. Upon creation of a new LWC Illuminated Cloud instantiates a HTML and JS file in addition to the `.css` and `.js-meta.xml` files.

Upon erasing of the HTML and JS files everything worked like a charm.

My guess is that importing the shared CSS from the `myComponent` is causing a conflict, if it contains HTML, JS files, as that component is not being imported in the HTML as a child component by `consumerComponent`.