# No MODULE named markup when importing CSS from a LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, import

This is related to my other thread [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/314518/trouble-importing-css-from-one-lwc-into-another).

So once I removed the HTML and JS files leaving just the CSS and XML files my *consumerComponent* is consuming the CSS from *myComponent* alright. I can see that it's picking up the css correctly.

However if I try to re-save the `consumerComponent` I get an error saying `Error:(1, 1) No MODULE named markup://c:myComponent found : [markup://c:myComponent]`

Has anybod successfully imported CSS from another LWC component? It appears that I can't make any further changes to my `consumerComponent` once I delete the *html* and *js* from `myComponent`. It just won't let me deploy although as I said the CSS is picking up correctly.

Comment: Did you delete the `myComponent.js-meta.xml` file, perchance? You do still need that file, despite not having a JS file in your component.

Comment: Did not delete it. It's still there. A colleague pulled my component and said the css and XML files are still there.

Answer (score 1):

The parent component and shared CSS component must be deployed together. In addition, if you're using the SFDX CLI, there is a [bug](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/492) related to the shared CSS deployment and retrieval. You should be able to successfully deploy using Workbench. I've found that I can deploy the shared CSS component itself through the CLI, but I have to use Workbench to deploy the parent components. Just remember that you have to include both the parent component and the shared CSS component in your Workbench package.