# Unable to deploy Aura component with nested LWC that uses shared CSS LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am using the new shared CSS LWC functionality as described in the Summer '20 release notes. I have an Aura component with a child LWC, and the child LWC imports the shared CSS LWC. I cannot deploy the Aura component without either (1) commenting out the child LWC, or (2) commenting out all references to the shared CSS in the child LWC (including grandchild components that also import the shared CSS). The failure occurs whether I attempt the deployment through the CLI or Workbench, even if I include the shared CSS component in the deployment package.

Error message:
`No MODULE named markup://c:ssfStyleLibrary found : [markup://c:SSFApplication, markup://c:ssf, markup://c:ssfBasicInfo]`

I am able to successfully deploy the shared CSS component from the CLI. I am able to successfully deploy the child LWC from Workbench (as long as I include the shared CSS LWC). If I comment out the the references to the shared CSS LWC in the child LWC, deploy the Aura component, then deploy the child LWC with nothing commented out, everything is deployed successfully. However, this process is tedious and doesn't fit within our deployment process, so I would like to know if there's anything I can do to avoid the commenting out/multiple deployments.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/314525/2984), but I can't close it as such yet. There's a Bug related to shared CSS and deployments. When it's fixed, it'll work as advertised.

Comment: This is a little different from the issue you linked. The bug for that issue is in the CLI. Workbench is a valid workaround. In this case, it doesn't work from Workbench, change sets, or the CLI.